# How can I apply the code I wrote in R to all files in a folder?

Tags: r, csv

I have the code below and I want the following code to be applied to all the csv files under the /usr/Desktop/prot folder, respectively, and only where it says "homo_tab_1" will output homo_tab_1, homo_tab_2 for each file.

```
homo_tab_1 = read.csv("proteins_homo.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

homo_tab_2 = homo_tab_1[,c(7,9:11)]
colnames(homo_tab_a)[2]="ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could read the data into a list and subset

```
files <- list.files(path = "/usr/Desktop/prot folder",
       pattern = "^homo_tab_\\d+.*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) 
   {
    tmp <- read.csv(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",")[, c(7, 9, 11)]
    names(tmp)[2] <- "ID"
    tmp
})
names(lst1) <- trimws(basename(files), whitespace = "\\.csv")
```

If we want to create different objects, use `list2env` (not recommended)

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```